# Pandas' convert_dtypes not working on numbers marked as objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, type-conversion

I have a pandas dataframe with columns of Dtype `object`. The values of these columns are very obviously numbers. However, `convert_dtypes` fails to recognize the number types and returns `object` again for all the columns. Here are some outputs that might illustrate the problem:

```
my_df.convert_dtypes().info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   A             3 non-null      object
 1   B             3 non-null      object
 2   C             3 non-null      object
 3   D             3 non-null      object
 4   E             3 non-null      object
 5   F             3 non-null      object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 168.0+ bytes
```

And these are the cells of the dataframe:

```
my_df
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   1   3   0   1   1
1   0   2   2   2   0   1
2   0   1   0   2   0   1
```

While I am able to convert the columns using other methods (e.g. `to_numeric`), I want to be able to have a generic way to do that, since the incoming data won't always be numeric, in which case `string` would do just fine.

The dataframe comes from another service, so let me know if you need more information about it. This is the reason why `to_numeric` wouldn't work. Basically, I need to convert the types to a number when possible and to string otherwise.

Python version is `3.8.5` and pandas version is `1.1.2`.

Answer (score 4):

If logic is convert to numeric if possible then use `errors='ignore'` parameter in [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for return original values of column if conversation failed (it means at least one non numeric value in column):

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  1  3  0  1  a
1  0  2  d  s  0  s
2  0  1  0  s  0  d


df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

print (df.dtypes)
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
D    object
E     int64
F    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: This should do the trick actually. Do you know why `convert_dtypes` doesn't work as expected though?

Comment: @IvayloToskov - No idea, maybe bug?

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines will do what you would intuitively expect `convert_dtypes` to do:

```py
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))
```

Note however that the index is reset by this operation, so you may want to modify this expression slightly if you want to retain the index.