# pandas type_convert does not work as expected

Tags: pandas

As shown in example below, Pandas `type_convert` does not correctly convert numbers coded as objects. I found others mention the same problem, for example in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65915289/1086346, but I find no follow up.

Working example creates columns (for x in [0,1,2,3]) "int_x", "alpha_x", "obj_x", and objective is to convert `obj_x` from string to integer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import random

random.seed(10)

N = 1000
C = 4
df_int = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(N, C)), columns=["int_" + str(i) for i in range(C)])
XX = [random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=N) for i in range(C)]
df_str = pd.DataFrame(np.array(XX).T, columns=['alpha_' + str(i) for i in range(C)])
YY = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(N, C)).astype(str)
df_obj = pd.DataFrame(YY, columns=["obj_" + str(i) for i in range(C)])
X = pd.concat([df_int, df_str, df_obj], axis=1)
X.shape
X.dtypes

Xn = X.convert_dtypes()
Xn.dtypes
```

The dtypes in X[obj_x] are "object" and they are not converted by `convert_dtypes`.

However, column-by-column manual application of `to_numeric` does work correctly, e.g.,

```
X2 = X2.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
X2.dtypes
```

Output shows the `obj_` columns are "int64", as they should be.

Is there a bug in convert_dtypes?

Comment: Hi, my understanding is that `convert_dtypes` purpose is to convert `object` values to their underlying dtype, in your example `str`, not to convert one specific dtype (str) to another (int64). So, I would argue that, in your example, the method is working as expected.

Comment: I don't think your interpretation matches the example in their docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html .  "For object-dtyped columns, if infer_objects is True, use the inference rules as during normal Series/DataFrame construction. Then, if possible, convert to StringDtype, BooleanDtype or an appropriate integer or floating extension type, otherwise leave as object."  In the example, it shows `object` being changed to `bool`.

Comment: All right. I wonder though: since you explicitly cast the underlying type (.astype(str)), could it be that StringDType simply takes precedence over integer type when convert_dtypes tries to convert values typed as objects?